# QTextEdit with page break

Tags: qt, text, qtextedit, page-break, qtextdocument

I need to break in pages instead of scrolling rich text content in a QTextEdit.

I tried to do this with QTextCursor and QFontmetrics but accuracy is not good enough.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance !!!!

K

Comment: Please read this book. [https://www.amazon.co.jp/Dive-into-unexplored-Programming-Qt6-ebook/dp/B0CJ2QVDVG/ref=sr_1_21?__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&crid=2QEXPDXZDHAG7&keywords=Qt&qid=1694895242&sprefix=qt%2Caps%2C231&sr=8-21]

Answer (score 0):

U Can Simulate that with a Simple Horizontal Layout , Scroll Area and more Textedit...
Add a New Textedit when the desired line of text is reached..