# QTextEdit Paginating

Tags: python, pagination, pyqt, qtextedit

I'm trying to write simple PyQT report editor and what I need is to exactly know what sizes the page has, MS-Word like. 
Today I found the following link:

[How to access QTextDocument pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874129/how-to-access-qtextdocument-pages)

that shows how to use an QPrinterPreviewDialog, and it seems to be the answer to my question, but I don't know how to transform it to Python. I have no idea how to implement QPrinterPreviewDialog into a QTextEdit. I tried to read the docs but without a example it's very hard to start.

Comment: The question you linked already asked for a solution in Python (although one in C++ was given). Now you ask again for a solution in Python. I might write one but in the other question.

Comment: I also found [Print A Text Through A Printer Using PyQt4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193920/print-a-text-through-a-printer-using-pyqt4). Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Please see this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318783/qtextedit-with-page-break